# While automating spotify with python, after running in terminal I get an error "No module named 'googleapiclient'"

Tags: python, macos, google-api, google-oauth, spotify

Link to video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J_qcttfnJA

I followed the entire tutorial and I thought I was free of problems until I tried running it in terminal. Below is the problem that I ran into.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

I have been installing different modules for a while and I could not find a solution to this. Does anyone know what the problem is and how i could fix it.

Comment: I believe this isn't a very good idea to post the link to tutorial - it's too long to  watch it.
Please show how your script looks like, how you launch it, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install google-api-python-client
```

Follow guide from the GitHub https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

Comment: Thanks, but after running it my program still did not seem fixed.

Comment: It stills showing the same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient' ?